# a wide knowledge of English vs. an extensive knowledge of English?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Which one is better? Which one is more natural? I'm writing a lesson review for a teacher on Italki website. I wanted to express that I'm grateful for the lesson, in particular for new English phrases. Although I provided the topic at the very last moment, the teacher was able to extend my vocabulary during the lesson without prior preparation.

[Related:](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106870/a-secretary-with-good-knowledge-of-english-a-or-no-article)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say a good knowledge of, a deep knowledge of, an extensive knowledge of, or a wide knowledge of.

However, the phrase "a good knowledge of" is the most common and idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

"Wide", "extensive", and "deep" could all work.